# Java: Thread safety in class with synchronized methods

Tags: java

I read that the following class is not thread safe since threads could read inconsistent data as there is a chance for a thread to read scaled version of `real` and unscaled version of `imaginary`. But I did not understand how.

I was under the impression that if a thread acquires a lock and is in `scale()` method, no other thread can be in `getReal()` or `getImaginary()` methods at the same time so that other threads cannot read 'half scaled' complex numbers. Is it not correct?

```
    class Complex 
    {   
         double real; 
         double imaginary;

         synchronized void scale(double scaleFactor)
         {
            real = real * scaleFactor;   
            imaginary = imaginary * scaleFactor; 
         }

         synchronized double getReal() 
         {
                return real;
         }

         synchronized double getImaginary() 
         {
               return imaginary;
         }
   }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the following scenario:

1. Thread A calls `getReal()`
2. Thread B calls `scale()`
3. Thread A calls `getImaginary()`

This way Thread A can indeed get inconsistent real and imaginary values.

The solution would be either to

- create a common synchronized getter method to return *both* values at once, or
- make the class immutable, as Vivien suggested.

Answer (score 4):

Not really a direct answer, but in your case, the best option is to make your class immutable. Each instance of `Complex` can't be changed after initialisation.

In this case, your scale method creates and returns a new `Complex` object with the new values.

Note this is how all JVM `Number` type works.

Comment: Just in case it's not obvious from your answer, I would add that the synchronized keywords should be removed as the immutability removes the need for the locks.

Answer (score 2):

> *no other thread can be in getReal() or getImaginary() methods at the same time so that other threads cannot read 'half scaled' complex numbers. Is it not correct?*

Yes, that's correct, however...

As Douglas points out, any client that needs access to the real and imaginary part has to perform two separate calls: one to `real()` and one to `imaginary()` (in which another thread could have called `scale` in between). You have no data-races, but the behavior may still depend on the scheduling.

Also, you need to **make the fields private**, otherwie a subclass or classes in the same package could see the "half-updated" complex number.

Answer (score 2):

Any client of your class has to call `getReal()` then `getImaginary()` if they want to do calculations with both parts.

These calls can surround a call to `scale()` from another thread.

Probably the best solution is to make the `Complex` class immutable, as otherwise you'll end up having to make many other bits complicated to lock & unlock the objects.